# How do I perform a forward-merge based on a previous change set with TFS?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, tfs

How do I perform a forward-merge based on a previous change set? I am using TFS, Visual Studio.

Comment: Hi Peter, did my answer helped?

Answer (score 1):

Forward-merge is not support in TFVC version control system. You could take a look at the description of [tf merge command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/merge-command).

If you really want this feature, you may have to use GIT version control system in TFS. Which one do you prefer, a blog for your reference: [**TFVC vs Git, a Feature Comparison**](https://simpletutorials.com/c/2040/TFS+2013%3A+TFVC+vs+Git,+a+Feature+Comparison)